# Programmatically create image from UILabel

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, uikit, core-graphics, uilabel

I want to use a UILabel to create an RGBA stream of bytes image representation programmatically (at runtime).

For example, I want to create a UILabel in a specific font and with specific text, turn this in to an NSData of RGBA unsigned bytes, and then from that point I can easily turn it in to an OpenGL texture and display it however I want.

It's important that I can know the dimensions of the resulting image, although if absolutely necessary I can create a very wide "blank" canvas to render this in to, and then at runtime detect the width and height myself by checking the bytes.

If I can achieve this through UIImage/CG it's a definite plus - and a solution with multiple render targets isn't reasonable/desired.

**Edit:** Placed a bounty; I had originally gotten this good-looking answer below from meronix, but now I got time to try it out and it does not work properly.  I need this working "yesterday" and am quite frustrated.  There's some nuance here, that someone who knows Cocoa drawing state better than me can surely catch.

Comment: Does it really have to be a UILabel, or do you just want to render some text into a texture to be used by OpenGL?

Comment: @zpasternack I really want to use UILabel because I want the convenience of using the wonderful and already-provided font rendering capabilities of Cocoa(Touch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGFloat scale  = [[[view window] screen] scale];
CGRect  bounds = [view bounds];

CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, CGRectGetWidth(bounds) * scale, CGRectGetHeight(bounds) * scale, 8, CGRectGetWidth(bounds) *
scale * 4, space, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, CGRectGetHeight(bounds) * scale);
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, scale, -scale);
[[view layer] renderInContext:ctx];
```

Then, use the bytes via `CGBitmapContextGetData(myContext)`.  No reason to bother with a UIImage

Answer (score 7):

You can "capture" (take a snapShot of) your UILabel, it's a subclass of UIView, so you can get its image.

use this class "CaptureView":

**CaptureView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <QuartzCore/CALayer.h>


@interface CaptureView : UIView {
@private
    UIImage *_imageCapture;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *imageCapture;

// Init
- (id)initWithView:(UIView *)view;

@end
```

**CaptureView.m**

```
#import "CaptureView.h"

// Private
@interface CaptureView (/* Private */)
- (void)settingImageFromView:(UIView *)view;
@end

// Public
@implementation CaptureView

@synthesize imageCapture = _imageCapture;

// Standard // UILabel
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        // Initialization code.
    }
    return self;
}

// Init
- (id)initWithView:(UIView *)view {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:[view frame]])) {
//  if ((self = [super initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)])) {
        // Initialization code.
        [self settingImageFromView:view];
    }
    return self;  
}

/*!
 @method     imageFromView:view
 @abstract   Esegue una Grab di una intera view
 @discussion Imposta l'immagine catturata eseguendo una copia dell'intera view 
 */
- (void)settingImageFromView:(UIView *)view {
    CGRect rect = [view bounds];  
 //   CGRect rect = CGRectMake(20, 30, 100, 100);  
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);  
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();  
    [view.layer renderInContext:context];  
    UIImage *imageCaptureRect;

    imageCaptureRect = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();  
    _imageCapture = imageCaptureRect;
//    _imageCapture = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();  
//    [_imageCapture retain];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();   
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code.
    CGPoint accPoint = CGPointMake(0,0);
    [_imageCapture drawAtPoint:accPoint];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [_imageCapture release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

so just initiate it passing your UILabel to it, so you'll get a Class with 
the UIImage *imageCapture property, so just get it and use it...

```
// in your class which wanna manage the captured image:
// in .h : #import "CaptureView.h"
CaptureView *cloneView = [[CaptureView alloc] initWithView:aUILabel];
//  [yourUIView addSubview:cloneView]; // eventually, to see it...
UIImage *myCapt = cloneView.imageCapture;
// ... your code to use myCapt
[cloneView release];
```

**EDIT:**

download this project:

http://meronix.altervista.org/captureUILabel.zip

the centered black-backGround text is a capture (an instance of the class: CaptureView) of the Gray-BackGround text (a UILabel) on top

Comment: I finally got around to trying this, and it doesn't actually work.  I first tried just "adapting" your code to run inline within my method, but then realized there was probably the subtlety of drawRect: being called at the right time by Cocoa. Unfortunately, I've now copied your code exactly, and it still doesn't work.  My "... your code to use myCapt" is code that takes the UIImage and uses `CGContextDrawImage` and friends to get raw bitmap data from it to immediately create an OpenGL texture.  But I simply get a crash at the end of my loop.

Comment: It seems that perhaps with the technique you propose, I must first create your image, then wait for a full draw cycle invoked by Cocoa, and then use the image data as I want?  This seems very difficult in practice..

Comment: and in fact, I tried, and waiting for the draw cycle to go through a few times has no effect.  There's definitely an issue here somewhere

Comment: @Nektarios: post your code, then. i'm sure i used it in some project/sample of mine and it works, i can search for them and maybe send you the sample/project, if i find them, but i cannot promise, it was so many time ago...

Comment: i don't find my project... but i took a look at my code: i try to explain how it work: when you init a CaptureView with: CaptureView *cloneView = [[CaptureView alloc] initWithView:aUILabel];
 you ask to that class to capture the "image" of a UILabel and use it in the image of itself (CaptureView is/hinerit from a UIImage)... to see if it works just use < [yourUIView addSubview:cloneView]; > , so you can see if the capture worked well...

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(yourLabel.bounds.size);
[yourLabel.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
CGImageRef viewImage = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() CGImage];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

`UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` returns an instance of `UIImage`.