# Convert the contents of a UILabel to an image and save it to disk

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I have a project for which I need a lot of individual words and phrases converted to a graphic format - preferably transparent PNG.

My thought was to load each word/phrase from a text file one at a time, put it into a UILabel and then grab the contents of that UILabel as a graphic and write it to a PNG file. Only problem is I'm not sure how to get the graphic part.

Ideally, the UILabel would resize to be exactly the right fit for the contents, so I don't end up with clipped words or lots of blank space.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I don't do Objective-C but I've got 25 years of C++.

Thanks,
Lindsay

Comment: You can capture the UILabel easily and get an image see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5522150/790842

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the label on self.view and call this method. 
This method will save the image in the photoAlbum, and wil return the image created, so you can use it.
    Hope this is what you have searched for.

```
- (UIImage *)createImagewithLabel {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, self.view.opaque, 0);

    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
//    _iv.image = image;
    return image;
}
```